# Facebook og meta not showing correct information

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta

I am trying to show a custom image when sharing my website on facebook. This is my current meta settings for facebook (all in the  tag):

```
<!--FACEBOOK-->
<meta property="og:title" content="Optimotive Technologies" >
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Optimotive Technologies">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://optimotive.github.io/" >
<meta property="og:description" content="Developing interior technology for the automotive sector." >
<meta property="og:image" content="https://scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/15577971_1140787826041531_2886517747532916403_o.png?oh=b474ab7cad8b9fe3c56537454771a44e&oe=5917241E" >
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="" >
<meta property="og:type" content="website" >
<meta property="og:locale" content="en-US" >
```

Facebook does not showing any of the indicated info when sharing.

Comment: Have you tried sharing the link before? Because then the page might need to be re-scraped. If that's the case, use the Facebook debugger to crawl your url again: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I have tried sharing the site before.

Comment: Then you probably have to make Facebook crawl your url again, otherwise you wont see any changes at all. I included the link to the debugger in my comment above. The problem might be somewhere else, this is just a first guess.

Comment: Why are you specifying a Facebook CDN URL as your image?